# Get value from nested radio button in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have just met problem when I was trying to get value from nested radio button, below is my code to show information to user.

```
<form:form action="make-test" method="post">
    <c:forEach var="question" items="${questions }">
        <c:out value="${question.question }"></c:out>
        <br>

        <c:forEach var="answer" items="${question.answers }">
            <input type="radio" name="${question.id }" value="${answer.id }" />
            <c:out value="${answer.answer }"></c:out>
            <br>
        </c:forEach>
        <br><br>
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

In this code, I can't use model attribute which spring filled properties of object(because this is list of object)

Have any way to process this value(converter or property editor which like Spring way) instead of processing @RequestBody by myself?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Follow your suggest, I changed my above code for suitable:

```
<form:form action="match" method="post" modelAttribute="questions">
    <c:forEach var="question" items="${questions }" varStatus="loopQuestion">
        <form:hidden path="questions[${loopQuestion.index }].id"/>
        <c:out value="${question.question }"></c:out>
        <br>

        <c:forEach var="answer" items="${question.answers }" varStatus="loopAnswer">
            <form:radiobutton path="question.answers[${loopAnswer.index }].id"
                value="${answer.id }"/>
            <c:out value="${answer.answer }"></c:out>
            <br>
        </c:forEach>
        <br><br>
    </c:forEach>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>       
</form:form>
```

Current error is `Invalid property 'questions' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]`, I know that question want to inform me that can't call getQuestions in ArrayList, how can I pass this?

Comment: You can use list as a model attribute

Comment: You can have a `List` of objects in Spring just fine.  In fact, Spring supports List, Set, and Map.  Where Spring struggles is with Collections of Collections.  What is the specific error you are seeing?

Comment: @CodeChimp Actually, I don't run it until now, because I don't know what model attribute I need to fill in form. It's always object. Like modelAttribute="question", not "listQuestion".

Comment: You access members of a Collection the same way you access members of a child object: Use dot notation.  For instance, taking your example above, I would expect you would have a `Question` that has a `List` of `Answer`s.  I would do something like `question.answer[1].id`, where [1] is the element of the answer list I wanted to access.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have just updated my code, but it's still have error.